# Is setting ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted for CurrentUser a security breach?

Tags: powershell, security, windows-10, executionpolicy

I have a couple of aliases I like to have in my PowerShell on my Windows 10.

I want them to persist between sessions, so I have put them in a profile.ps1 file under C:\Users{username}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell.

I am getting this annoying "cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system." error message, and have found this page on how to get rid of it:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e4a9006-d47d-4e19-96f4-10327ae0c5b1/not-able-to-run-script-in-windows-10?forum=winserverpowershell

In here someone says that this line will help:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Verbose
```

But is it hazardous to just set the execution policy to unrestricted for my user?

Comment: I'm actually planning to vote to close this as primarily opinion based. So here are my opinions. Is it less safe? Most definitely. Is it a security breach? Well, that depends on your definition of security breach. Personally I set my execution policy to RemoteSigned. This means I can have a profile but cannot run scripts that are downloaded from the internet without first changing their ADS.

Comment: Actually having a profile isn't the reason I use RemoteSigned. I realized that might be misleading. I could sign the profile if I wanted to. The reason I use RemoteSigned is that I often spend my day testing techniques in powershell and showing other people that just come by my desk how to do things in powershell. Often by quickly mocking up a script for what they want. It is not worth the effort to sign these little 10-20 line scripts every time that I create one. But that is my environment and the way that I use powershell. You have to make these decisions for yourself.

Comment: Execution policy is a safety feature, not a security feature. No matter what the execution policy is, we can still run scripts by setting an execution policy for the PowerShell process, and this does not require elevated privileges. A restrictive execution policy only helps prevent a user from accidentally running a script they shouldn't. It won't stop a user from running any script at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExecutionPolicy` is not a security boundary. As someone opined elsewhere in a comment, it is a safety feature. Think seat belt not door lock. But seat belts mitigate risk so it's better to use them than not. `ExecutionPolicy` mitigates the risk of unintentionally running malicious code. The generally recommended minimum policy is `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: Your analogy expresses more concisely what I was trying to say; thanks.